# Capture Undo/Redo events in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I am creating a Photoshop plugin and a flex panel. I need to capture undo/redo event in Photoshop and send notification to flex. but I am unable to capture undo/redo events.

Can anyone guide me how can I capture these events in my plugin?

Thanks

Comment: Flex panel is not Flex framework. You have missinsterted a tag.